# ffprobe frame information in decode or presentation order?

Tags: ffprobe

When you do a command like:

ffprobe -show_frames *inputfile*

In what order does it give you the frames? Because Presentation order and Decode Order will be different... I am thinking that depending on which order it gives you, then others who are trying to count the size of the GOP by grepping for pict-type and then counting it that way may be getting slightly different results?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presentation order; see the `coded_picture_number` progression - for streams with B-frames, the sequence won't be monotonic.

Comment: Thanks. So just to confirm that the coded_picture_number is the presentation Index?

Comment: No, it's the encoding order, hence the decoding order.